# Cannot find HST profiler

Tags: c#

I need little help on code coverage in .Net. I read an online blog where the author mentioned that there exists a base profiler source code from which he derived his code coverage profiler, is located by default in

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET\FrameworkSDK\Tool Developers Guide\Samples\profiler\hst_profiler

I have Visual Studio Professional 2012 installed on my machine but after a lot of searching inside .Net Framework folders on my machine and googling on the net I couldn't locate hst_profiler folder.

Any insights on this one will be greatly welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: Did he mean vsts profiler?

Comment: no he meant hot spot tracker.

Comment: The only thing I've seen about hst is an old article from 2001.  I'm assuming it's no longer around.  Why not take a look at something a little bit newer for increasing your code coverage like Nunit?  http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=quickStart&r=2.2.10

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, let me do a little study on NUnit and I will get back with my view on it.

Comment: No problem.  You can also look at some other newer things like mock frameworks (check out rhino mocks) or something like specflow which is also very nice for increasing code coverage.

Comment: Thanks Timothy, do you know which is a popular tool(for code coverage) these days for code written in c# using MS Visual Studio .

Comment: NUnit is probably the most popular by far.  Find the nuget package an instructions to get started here:  http://www.nuget.org/packages/nunit

Comment: I tried NCover that comes with TestDriven.Net and it's just so simple.Right Click your unit test class library and hit Run Tests,it will also pull up a report for you.